# Does Yeppp! support multiply accumulate operations on arrays

Tags: math, yeppp

The Yeppp! math library seems to support basic vector operations such as add, subtract and multiplication of two vectors.

A common vector operation is multiply-accumulate, where each element a in vector A is transformed by each element b in Vector B and some scalar c.

a = a + c*b

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation

Is this supported?

Answer (score 1):

As of Yeppp! 1.0.0, no. This operation is implemented in Yeppp! sources, but currently disabled.